# setTimeOut() gets repeated in Angular Lifecycle Hooks: ngDoCheck, ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: angular, settimeout

### Reproducibility

I have a small TypeScript code snippet as below:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewChecked 1");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("ngAfterViewChecked 2");
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Function `setTimeOut()` is supposed to get the lambda function called after 1 second and *then stop*. However, the hook ngAfterViewChecked() is called continuously (excerpt from Chrome Developer Tool Console):

```
00:36:50.827 home.component.ts:53 ngAfterViewChecked 1
00:36:51.842 home.component.ts:55 ngAfterViewChecked 2
00:36:51.843 home.component.ts:53 ngAfterViewChecked 1
00:36:52.843 home.component.ts:55 ngAfterViewChecked 2
00:36:52.844 home.component.ts:53 ngAfterViewChecked 1
00:36:53.845 home.component.ts:55 ngAfterViewChecked 2
00:36:53.846 home.component.ts:53 ngAfterViewChecked 1
00:36:54.848 home.component.ts:55 ngAfterViewChecked 2
...
```

**Without** the `setTimeOut()`, function `ngAfterViewChecked()` is called once. This issue occurs also with `ngDoCheck()`, `ngAfterContentChecked()`.

### Test with other Angular Lifecycle Hooks

The same code body, **with or without** `setTimeOut()`, declared in `constructor()`, `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterContentInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()`, gets called once as expected.

### Environment

- The program is very simple (like "Hello World" for Angular). No 3rd party library.
- Both Angular 5 & 6 have this issue (lower versions haven't been tested). They were installed separately in different machines.

  ```
  Angular CLI: 6.0.8
  Node: 8.11.3
  OS: win32 x64
  Angular: 6.0.9


  Angular CLI: 1.7.4
  Node: 8.11.1
  OS: win32 x64
  Angular: 5.2.10
  ```
- Windows 8.1 x64.
- Google Chrome 67 (64 bit).

### My guess

The hooks `constructor()`, `ngOnInit()`, `ngAfterContentInit()`, `ngAfterViewInit()` are called once in the entire Lifecycle of a Component, regardless of how its content evolves through out its life. So this issue reasonably doesn't happen in these hooks.

With `ngDoCheck()`, `ngAfterContentChecked()` and `ngAfterViewChecked()`, they get called when Angular *detects changes*. But as showed in the lambda function body, only simple `console.log()` is used. I think Angular might intercept the `setTimeOut()` call and blindly believes that there could have been some changes, so it starts the Change Detection process, which leads to what we have seen: calls *chained infinitely*.

### Question

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Have you read this: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Feature - Angular's change detection runs after asynchronous operations complete (like setTimeout) - so the setTimeout itself it causing `ngAfterViewChecked` to run, and vice versa.

You can run things outside of Angular's Zone if you don't want that to happen, i.e.

```
   ngAfterViewChecked(){
    console.log("ngAfterViewChecked 1");

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("ngAfterViewChecked 2");
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

You can inject NgZone in your constructor, i.e. `private ngZone: NgZone`. Check out the relationship between Angular and zone.js for more info.

Comment: I didn't know about `runOutsideAngular`. A useful thing to have learned. :)

Comment: @kshetline, me too. Matmo, is it a new Angular 6 feature?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide No, its been there from the start, see https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html